# Angular2 ngModel undefined with <input> tag

Tags: select, angular, calendar, semantic-ui, angular2-ngmodel

I'm using Angular2 and a forked version of Semantic-UI (that includes calendar module). I'm using `calendar` and `dropdown` features:

```
constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        jQuery('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
        jQuery('.ui.calendar').calendar({ type: 'date' });
    }, 1000);)
}
```

Here is [my Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYGkN3qfPZGMSN7UEXKs).

As you can see I can't get input from calendar selection.

I can't understand what could be the glitch. Can you figure out what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Angular2? Beta 0 is quite old.

Answer (score 3):

For some unknown reason **[(ngModel)]** is not getting updated.

But if its  a matter of getting date only, you could use **#templateVariable** as shown here.

**Working DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/X8Gjwzd62DvYN1S8jrFv?p=preview**

Using **#TemplateVariable**

```
<input #date  type="text" placeholder="Date">

<button (click)="test(date.value)">test</button> 

test(date):void { 
    console.log(date);
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

Using **@ViewChild**

```
@ViewChild('date') date:ElementRef;

 test(date):void { 
       console.log(this.date.nativeElement.value);
        console.log(date);
        console.log(this.name);
 }
```

Comment: Any way to make it working without passing that templateVariable in the `test` function? I do not have Test button in my real code.

Comment: I updated my plunker to access data in ts code using ViewChild

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Since i'm using `ReactiveFormsModule` can you please update your code using `formControl` instead of `ngModel` for every element of the form (calendar and select)?.

Comment: Anyway using your code in my project breaks something: `GET http://localhost:3000/user/traceur 404 (Not Found)`